# When pushing a modal view, how do I pass data on the way back to parent?

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2, watchos

I am working on some Watch OS 2 programming in swift. I have two view controllers, lets call them 'parent' and 'child'. When a button is pressed on 'parent', I push the child view controller modally using the following code:

```
presentControllerWithName("LogDrinkInterface", context: nil)
```

On the 'child' view controller, I have 4 potential buttons. When any button is pressed, the modal dismisses and returns to the parent using the following line:

```
self.dismissController()
```

I need to pass data from 'child' to 'parent' depending on which button is pressed. Let's say I want to return an int that is either 1,2,3, or 4 which would indicate which button was pressed.

Comment: Use a delegate pattern

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Paulw11 - this is a good use case for the `delegate` paradigm. You'll make the `parentVC` the `delegate` of the `childVC`. There are a plethora of tutorials online of how the paradigm works and its various implementation methods.